# Using item option as the search parameter of an orders tag

Tags: cartthrob

I have a Matrix field set up as a CartThrob options field and would like to list orders based on whether a certain option was part of the order.

Something like this:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
      channel='orders'
      disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
      search:{order_items}{item:entry_id}{/order_items}="1088"
      }
      <tr>
        {order_items}
          <td>{item:entry_id}</td>
          <td>{item:title}</td>
        {/order_items}
        <td>{order_customer_full_name}</td>
        <td>{order_customer_email}</td>
      </tr>  
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is it possible to use options like that in the search parameter? It seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have weird EE template parsing order issues doing this. I think you'd need an outer loop to look it up, maybe with a custom query, and feed that to exp:channel:entries or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt.

It seems what I was trying isn't possible but I have something similar working by using stash to set a list of orders with the item option as a stash variable. Than filtering it down based on that.